# Dask difference between .take and .compute

Tags: python, dask

I don't fully understand the semantics of `.take` and `.compute`.

From the `dask.bad.Bag` api docs:

> Bag.compute(**kwargs) Compute this dask collection
>
> Bag.take(k[, npartitions, compute, warn]) Take the first k elements.

This makes me think that If I compute the whole collection and then take one element `.take` will not trigger a re-computations. But it does. So when should someone use take vs compute? Is compute not supposed to be used during development when you want to inspect the result of a computation? Because if `take(N)` has the same result and using compute doesn't save anything, why use compute?